# Wineskin app font problem

Tags: font, wine

I'm running a vocabulary app and I've a problem with fonts as you can see from the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

On another macbook it works fine, on this one it has this issue, I've no idea on what it could be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it by going into package contents and used the wineskin app with winetricks to install `allfonts` and upgraded bundled wine version

Comment: This did not work for QQ游戏